# How can I make card text the same height?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have a react app where I have cards with different amount of text inside of them. I am able to get the heart icon and price at the bottom the same height, but having difficulty with the image and the text.

This is what I currently have:
[image]

I'm also using tailwind CSS, this is currently what I have.

```
        <div className='singleCard h-full flex flex-col mx-1 transition ease-in-out delay-150 hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100 hover: duration-300 hover:shadow-lg' key={item.id}>
          < button className='mx-1 my-1' value={item.brand + item.product_type} onClick={() => { changeIcon(index); saveDispatch({ type: 'SAVE', saveIt: item }) }}>
            {likedIndex[index] ?
              (
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" className="redHeart w-6 h-6">
                  <path d="M11.645 20.91l-.007-.003-.022-.012a15.247 15.247 0 01-.383-.218 25.18 25.18 0 01-4.244-3.17C4.688 15.36 2.25 12.174 2.25 8.25 2.25 5.322 4.714 3 7.688 3A5.5 5.5 0 0112 5.052 5.5 5.5 0 0116.313 3c2.973 0 5.437 2.322 5.437 5.25 0 3.925-2.438 7.111-4.739 9.256a25.175 25.175 0 01-4.244 3.17 15.247 15.247 0 01-.383.219l-.022.012-.007.004-.003.001a.752.752 0 01-.704 0l-.003-.001z" />
                </svg>
              )
              : (
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5" stroke="currentColor" className="w-6 h-6" >
                  <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M21 8.25c0-2.485-2.099-4.5-4.688-4.5-1.935 0-3.597 1.126-4.312 2.733-.715-1.607-2.377-2.733-4.313-2.733C5.1 3.75 3 5.765 3 8.25c0 7.22 9 12 9 12s9-4.78 9-12z" />
                </svg>
              )
            }

          </button>
          <Link to={`/product/${item.id}`} name={item.brand}>
            <img className='productImg ml-8 mb-2 md:ml-12 xl:ml-20' src={item.api_featured_image} alt={item.brand + item.product_type}></img>
            {/* To display the brand name with as sentence case */}
            <div className='productText px-2 flex flex-col content-end'>
              <p className='productType'>{item?.product_type ? item.product_type.charAt(0) + item.product_type.slice(1).toLowerCase().split('_').join(' ') : item.product_type}</p>
              <p className='productBrand'>
                {item?.brand ? item.brand.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.brand.slice(1).toLowerCase() : item.brand} </p>
              <p className='productName'>{item?.name ? item.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.name.slice(1).toLowerCase() : item.name}</p>
            </div>
          </Link>
          <div className='flex flex-row mt-auto mx-2 my-2'>
            <div className='mr-auto mt-auto'>
              <p className='productPrice'><span className='circleShadow '>£{Number(item.price).toFixed(2)}</span>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className='addToCart ml-auto mt-auto '>
              <button className='basketProduct' onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'ADD', payload: item })}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBasketShopping} />
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

This is my CSS

```
.productText{
    overflow-wrap: break-word
}

.productImg{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}

.productType{
    color:rgba(253,210,97,255);
    font-weight: bold;
}

.productBrand, .productName{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.basketProduct:hover{
    color:rgba(253,210,97,255);
}

.redHeart{
    fill:red;
}

.circleShadow{
    background-image: url('../Images/Backgrounds/grey.png');
    background-size: 22px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I've tried using margin-bottom:auto with no luck!

Comment: Use aspect-ratio: 3/4; and size

Comment: You'd do much better to extract the React from this question and just present HTML and CSS (in a demo snippet using the editor). We'd then be able to see and troubleshoot the problem. As it is, we're left imagining it. Please see [ask] and don't tag your titles.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the aspect ratio, then you can set the aspect-ratio: 3/4; and width: 100%; to the image. But if it is not allowed to modify the ratio of aspect, Then you can add a new div to the component view part. After add a new div, Then set the width and height as static. Then put the image tag inside the div and set display: flex; align-items: center; to the div. Remember to set the width to the div and set width:100% to the image. Hope this could be help you.